# Why is this giving me an error and how can I append the div in to the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the error that is giving me:

[image: error message image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Error at app.js 7

```js
const flexContainer = document.querySelector('.flex-container')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  div.classList.add('.item-1')
  flexContainer.appendChild(div)
})
```

```css
body{
  background: #333;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flexbox-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flexbox{
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  background: white;
}

.item-1{
  min-height: 200px;
}
.item-2{
  min-height: 200px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <button class="btn">add card</button>
  <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox item-1"></div>
    <div class="flexbox item-2"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etfuw.png)

Comment: `<div class="flexbox-container">` and `document.querySelector(".flex-container")`... It's a mystery.

Comment: Maybe you see the different spellings of your css class rightaway? the class' name is flexbox-container, but in your javascript you refer to it as flex-container. This cannot be found for obvious reasons.

Comment: ....yeah that's a definite typo. but still wont work - because of this => `div.classList.add('.item-1')` should be `div.classList.add('item-1')`

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the class `.flex-container` but in your HTML that class doesn't exist ( there is a `.flexbox-container`) so that is why you get a null on the variable `flexContainer`

Answer (score -1):

Here you go :

```js
const flexContainer = document.querySelector('.flexbox-container')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  div.classList.add('flexbox', 'item-1');
  flexContainer.appendChild(div)
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flexbox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  background: white;
}

.item-1 {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.item-2 {
  min-height: 200px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <button class="btn">add card</button>
  <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox item-1"></div>
    <div class="flexbox item-2"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah... Thanks @AlwaysHelping